# How many times does the value A from the column 2 appears with the value B from the column 1 (metadata)

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata

So I have a table X where

colum 1  column 2
valueB   valueA
valueB   valueC
valueB   valueC
valueB   valueC
valueD   valueA
valueD   valueA
valueD   valueC
valueD   valueC

And i want a result like this:

colum 1 colum2 number
valueB valueA 1
valueB valueC 3
valueD ValueA 2
valueD valueC 2

where number is how many times the value from column 2 is with the value from column 1

How can I do it? (I'm doing this query on the meta data)

This is how I made it:

```
SELECT table_name, data_type, count(data_type) 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE OWNER = 'ZZ' 
group by table_name, DATA_TYPE 
order by table_name;
```

Comment: This is called a `group by`.  Aggregation queries are a basic SQL construct.  You should learn how to use the language.

Comment: I already used group by, but I only get colum1 colum2 wihtout the number, and if I try to count it counts all the times that valueA appears in his column wihout taking in count the value from colum1

Comment: It would help if you showed your current query then.

Comment: @AlejandroCordoba . . . If you have a query (even one that doesn't work), then you should edit it an put it in your answer; this shows both effort and enough knowledge to understand the answer.  My first comment was driven by the point that explaining aggregation to someone who doesn't know SQL is too broad a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You were right I didnt even put my progress, already found the solution, sorry!

Comment: There's no need for `COUNT(data_type)` here ... you can just use `COUNT(*)`.